# Why are outputs from the first component not passed to the second's inputs directly in a coupled group using a NonlinearBlockGS solver?

Tags: python, openmdao

I am running into an issue with a `Group` which includes feedback between its subsystems in OpenMDAO. I am using the `NonlinearBlockBS` solver. I expect a Gauss-Seidel solver to run the subsystems sequentially, passing outputs from earlier blocks on to the others' inputs. However, this does not seem to happen when I implement this in OpenMDAO.

I have made an example script that demonstrates this problem:

```
class A(ExplicitComponent):

    def setup(self):
        self.add_input('x', shape=1)
        self.add_input('b', shape=1)
        self.add_output('a', shape=1)

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
        outputs['a'] = inputs['x'] + 2 * inputs['b']
        print('A: x = {:1.0f}, b = {:1.0f}, a = {:1.0f}'.format(inputs['x'][0], inputs['b'][0], outputs['a'][0]))


class B(ExplicitComponent):

    def setup(self):
        self.add_input('x', shape=1)
        self.add_input('a', shape=1)
        self.add_output('b', shape=1)

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
        outputs['b'] = inputs['x'] - 0.5 * inputs['a']
        print('B: x = {:1.0f}, a = {:1.0}, b = {:1.0f}'.format(inputs['x'][0], inputs['a'][0], outputs['b'][0]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ivc = IndepVarComp()
    ivc.add_output('x', val=3.)

    coupled_group = Group()
    coupled_group.add_subsystem('A', A(), promotes=['*'])
    coupled_group.add_subsystem('B', B(), promotes=['*'])
    coupled_group.nonlinear_solver = NonlinearBlockGS()

    prob = Problem()
    model = prob.model = Group()
    model.add_subsystem('I', ivc, promotes=['*'])
    model.add_subsystem('C', coupled_group, promotes=['*'])

    prob.setup()
    prob.run_model()
```

Two components, `A` and `B`, are coupled by their outputs, `a` and `b`. They also share a parameter, `x`, which is set initially by the `IndepVarComp`. When run, the code produces the following output:

```
 =
 C
 =
 A: x = 3, b = 1, a = 7
 B: x = 3, a = 1, b = 4
 A: x = 3, b = 1, a = 7
 B: x = 3, a = 7, b = 1
 A: x = 3, b = 1, a = 7
 B: x = 3, a = 7, b = 1
 NL: NLBGS Converged in 1 iterations
```

The `b` parameter, taken as input by `A`, has not been defined yet when `A` is run first. Therefore, it takes an initial value of 1. This is as expected. Then `B` is run, which should take the output from `A`, `a = 7`, but instead `a` is also set to an initial guess of 1. This is not what I expect when using the Gauss-Seidel method.

The fact that `B` does not get the updated value of `a` after `A` is run does not impact the fact that this system converges to the correct solution in this case. However, in my case `a = 1` is not a valid input for `B`. Therefore the system fails to converge.

Am I doing something wrong here? What can I do to make sure `B` is given the updated value of `a` the first run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In OpenMDAO variables are defined as implicit functions of all other variables. This is a major difference compared to flow based architectures, where components are defined as explicit functions. See [Flow based architecture and MAUD architecture][1]. In OpenMDAO instead of this a nonlinear system of equations is solved for residuals. So it is normal, that in the first step the default value is used in component `B` for input `a` (the input of `B.a` is `A.a`, so `B.a` will be equal in the first computation to the default of `A.a`)

If `a` is not a valid value in your system `B`, initialize it with suitable default value (now you are only specifying the shape in the setup, and not the value.). The signature of the method for adding an input is `add_input(self, name, val=1.0, shape=None, src_indices=None, flat_src_indices=None, units=None, desc='')`, so your default value will be 1.0 if you do not specify it.
I rewrote your classes to start with initial values defined in the setup for your variables. For component `B` `a` is passed from the setup of `A`, and not the first computation of `A`. Same holds for `b` in component `A`. After this the solver will try to minimize the residuals, to drive `B.a-A.a` and `B.b-A.b` to zero.

```
class A(ExplicitComponent):

    def setup(self):
        self.add_input('x', shape=1)
        self.add_input('b', val=2)
        self.add_output('a', val=1)

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
        outputs['a'] = inputs['x'] + 2 * inputs['b']
        print('A: x = {:1.0f}, b = {:1.0f}, a = {:1.0f}'.format(inputs['x'][0], inputs['b'][0], outputs['a'][0]))


class B(ExplicitComponent):

    def setup(self):
        self.add_input('x', shape=1)
        self.add_input('a', val=3)
        self.add_output('b', val=4)

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
        outputs['b'] = inputs['x'] - 0.5 * inputs['a']
        print('B: x = {:1.0f}, a = {:1.0}, b = {:1.0f}'.format(inputs['x'][0], inputs['a'][0], outputs['b'][0]))
```

The first step of the solver:

```
=
C
=
A: x = 3, b = 4, a = 11
B: x = 3, a = 1e+00, b = 2
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygBdn.png Hwang, JT and Martins, JRRA: "A Computational Architecture for Coupling Heterogeneous Numerical Models and Computing Coupled Derivatives"